# How to programmatically change the resolution of a specific monitor?

Tags: delphi

How do you programmatically change the resolution of a specific monitor? For instance can the secondary monitor resolution be programmatically changed?

Comment: If I have correctly understood your question - I hope you're at least considering asking the user... There's no Delphi way. You'll be probably using `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx` in the end, but have to verify if there's a second monitor first (that you can have with `TScreen`) and it supports your resolution (`EnumDisplaySettings`).

Comment: I mean, about Delphi Way, is how implement it in delphi code for second monitor, because most articles talking about setting for first or primary monitor

Comment: I have no idea what articles are talking about. If you read my previous comment, you'll find the API that's able to modify display settings of secondary monitors in it.

Comment: Can you give me some code snippet for it, I just a beginner about it, it seems WinAPI things, just confusing using its function, such as EnumDisplayDevice, EnumDisplaySettings, ChangeDisplaySettings, and so on. How to make it looks easier to use like SetResolution(MySecondaryMonitorDevice,800,600), for example.

Comment: When you first asked this question, we closed it, and deleted it, because it made no sense. That means that you must not ask the exact same question. We understand that you are stuck. But you can't ask the same question over and over. You must fix the question.

Comment: Do i ask same question?

Comment: I never multi post my 'Set 2nd monitor resolution in delphi way' ! First post is 'Set 2nd monitor resolution'. I hope you see the different, and you said that i post this title over and over?

Comment: The question you posted before with almost identical text is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094151/set-2nd-monitor-resolution

Comment: So what is the problem? I fixed it before you commented here, right?

Comment: @TLama:  I hope you are not delete it, maybe somebody will fix it like I fixed my question. Right, David? :)

Comment: The question is not fixed in my view. It's very unclear what you want. Are you just asking how to programmatically change the display resolution of a specific monitor?

Comment: Yes, as simple as that. Programmatically. This forum for developers, is it? Can we ask out of programming?

Comment: @TLama - RE edit: There seems to be some confusion here, display devices are not primary, secondary. Monitors are. This is not nit-picking, f.i. my secondary monitor is on \\.\DISPLAY7 (6th display device). The poster seemed to ask to change resolution of his 2nd monitor in his OP.

Comment: @Sertac, that's right, thanks for the hint! Fixed...

Comment: @gogglepink The question is fixed now. But not by you. I can't understand why you didn't edit it. My assumption is that perhaps you don't realise that you can. Stack Overflow is a wiki. Posts can be edited and updated and improved. Yours needed it. TLama and Rob Mensching did the work. But next time you should do it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : No, I knew that I can edit my questions. But I dont know what makes other confuse with my words (question). So TLama changed it, because he is very understand with my problem and what I want (he gave a good answer to my question, then Sertac fixed it, so it works on XP)

Comment: @gogglepink Have it your way then. I'm only trying to help you get the most out of Stack Overflow. But you don't have to listen to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following function might be your starting point. It tries to change the resolution of a display device with index specified by the `Index` parameter (if exists such) to a width and height (in pixels) given by the `Width`, `Height` parameters. The function returns True, if the display device with given index is found and the resolution of it has been successfully changed, False otherwise.

You haven't specified whether you want to change the resolution permanently (if you want to store the setting changes), or change it only temporarily. The following example does it temporarily, but you can quite simply change this behavior if you use in the second [`ChangeDisplaySettingsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function call the `CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY` value for the `dwflags` parameter:

```
function ChangeMonitorResolution(Index, Width, Height: DWORD): Boolean;
var
  DeviceMode: TDeviceMode;
  DisplayDevice: TDisplayDevice;
begin
  Result := False;
  ZeroMemory(@DisplayDevice, SizeOf(DisplayDevice));
  DisplayDevice.cb := SizeOf(TDisplayDevice);
  // get the name of a device by the given index
  if EnumDisplayDevices(nil, Index, DisplayDevice, 0) then
  begin
    ZeroMemory(@DeviceMode, SizeOf(DeviceMode));
    DeviceMode.dmSize := SizeOf(TDeviceMode);
    DeviceMode.dmPelsWidth := Width;
    DeviceMode.dmPelsHeight := Height;
    DeviceMode.dmFields := DM_PELSWIDTH or DM_PELSHEIGHT;
    // check if it's possible to set a given resolution; if so, then...
    if (ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(PChar(@DisplayDevice.DeviceName[0]), 
      DeviceMode, 0, CDS_TEST, nil) = DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
    then
      // change the resolution temporarily (if you use CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY
      // value for the penultimate parameter, the graphics mode will also
      // be saved to the registry under the user's profile; for more info
      // see the ChangeDisplaySettingsEx reference, dwflags parameter)
      Result := ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(PChar(@DisplayDevice.DeviceName[0]),
        DeviceMode, 0, 0, nil) = DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL;
  end;
end;
```

An example how to change resolution of a secondary display device (device with index 1) to 800x600:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ChangeMonitorResolution(1, 800, 600) then
    ShowMessage('Resolution of display device with index 1 has been changed!')
  else
    ShowMessage('Display device with index 1 doesn''t exist, doesn''t support ' +
      'resolution 800x600 or changing failed due to a reason, which you might ' +
      'know if the author of this function wouldn''t be so lazy!');
end;
```

Comment: I got error : 'Access violation at address xxxxxx in module 'GDI32.dll'. Read of address yyyyyyy'

Comment: I've been missing `dmFields` flags (lost while writing the answer), but even this is not the reason for such critical failure, I'd say. Which version of Delphi/Windows are you using ?

Comment: I am using Delphi 7 dan my OS WinXP Professional version 2002 Service Pack 2

Comment: I hope we're talking about real, non-virtual machine, do we ?

Comment: Ok thanks you've answered my question above, I would try to use win 7 in other day or waiting somebody to reply my error message.

Comment: Yup, we are talking about real machine, two monitors in reality

Comment: Just for being definitely sure. Are you trying this in a plain new project and the only thing that is being called is this function and nothing around ? If so, then I must have made a big mistake (or there's a serious bug on XP) because Windows API doesn't behave so exceptionally.

Comment: Yes I just create new project, add your codes, set my monitors to extended display, and run the project and clicked the button

Comment: Does it fail the same for both your devices ? If not, could you please check what's the value of the `DisplayDevice.StateFlags` for a device on which it fails ?

Comment: @TLama - I took my time to test this on XP. The OS doesn't like garbage in the structures.

Comment: @Sertac, thanks a lot! I was blindly hoping that it takes only those two attributes into account.

Comment: @TLama - Actually it may just be the 'dmDriverExtra' of the DevMode causing trouble, but I think it's better to be on the safe side. But I can see no reason to zero the TDisplayDevice, however, my tests didn't go right without it.